# Combining Razor, Ajax, JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, razor

I try to make following parts run, but always failed. The objective is: if a target in combobox is selected, the mediaId's combobox should be filled with respective values. At this moment I just emulate the values of mediaId combobox. Can anyone show me how to combine them correctly? Thx in advance.

The view Medium.cshtml:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/PartialLoad.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Files[i].TargetId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Files[i].PTargetId, (ViewData["targets"] as SelectList).MakeSelection(Model.Files[i].PTargetId))
</div>
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Files[i].MediaId)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Files[i].MediaId, (ViewData["mediaIds"] as SelectList).MakeSelection(1)) 
</div>
```

The javascript partialload.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#targets").change(function () { GetMValues("#targets", "#mediaIds"); });
});

function ClearDrop(objSource) {
    $(objSource).empty();
}

function GetMValues(objSource, objDest) {
    var url = '/GetMValues/';
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(objSource).val() },
        function (data) {
            ClearDrop(objDest); $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                $(objDest).append("<option value='" + optionData.Value + "'>" + optionData.Text + "</option>");
            });
        });
}
```

The homecontroller.cs

```
public ActionResult GetMValues(String id)
{
    int myId = 0;
    int.TryParse(id, out myId);

    var mediumIds = new List<long>();
    int max = myId + 3;
    // just to emulate the data in the list
    for ( long l = 1 ; l < max ; l++ ){
        mediumIds.Add(l);
    }
    var select = new SelectList(mediumIds, "PTargetId", "TargetId");
    return Json(select, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); //allow get needed to allow get calls
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `'/GetMValues/'` is the correct URL? Seems like it should be `'/Home/GetMValues/'` for a HomeController.

Comment: Does /home/getmvalues/ or /getmvalues/ return the correct JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Here you are using an id selector for the dropdownlist: `$("#targets")` but your dropdown doesn't seem to have such id. Maybe you want to assign it an id or a class:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Files[i].PTargetId, 
    (ViewData["targets"] as SelectList).MakeSelection(Model.Files[i].PTargetId),
    new { id = "targets" }
)
```

But because this seems to be repeated and you cannot have multiple elements with the same id a class selector is probably more appropriate:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    model => model.Files[i].PTargetId, 
    (ViewData["targets"] as SelectList).MakeSelection(Model.Files[i].PTargetId),
    new { @class = "targets" }
)
```

and then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".targets").change(function () { 
        ...
    });
});
```

Same remark obviously for `#mediaIds`.

Comment: I have updated the code both for targets and mediaIds. The content of DropDownList is not changed whatever I select the target. I want like this: if I select target 1, the mediaIds should contain 1,2,3,4 as DropDownList. If I select target 2, the mediaIds should contain 1,2,3,4,5. I am sure the code for mediaId in the view is wrong, because it shows only 1 and 99 as content. But I don't know how to fix it. Would you show me how? Thx in advance.